# Is it possible to improve word suggestions?

Tags: keyboard, auto-correct

I used to use the "swiftkey" app for writing, and was very pleased with the suggestions they generated. I have now changed to 8pen "keyboard" instead I'm very pleased but miss the good autocompletes, is there someway to improve the autocompletes without using swiftkey? Changing suggestion engine, importing language from facebook etc. My phone is rooted

Comment: The quality of Swiftkey's predictions is basically [their entire sales pitch](http://www.swiftkey.net/about/what-is-swiftkey). It seems unlikely that there's a way to reach that without simply using Swiftkey - you'll probably just end up having to decide which features are most important.

Comment: It doesn't have to be that awesome, just better than the regular one. Also I payed for swiftkey, so maybe get the dicitionary from swiftkey and add it to the system somehow.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but it could be if you find it useful.  Swype is another keyboard with which you can input text (composed of recognised words) easily. If not aware, try to see www.swype.com

Answer (score 1):

Swiftkey have an article on this although it's a little vague, it's seems more like they are describing how to use entirely different keyboards [here](http://support.swiftkey.net/knowledgebase/articles/9103-i-want-to-use-a-different-keyboard-how-do-i-switc):

> **I want to use a different keyboard, how do I switch?**
>
> Press and hold in any text field to bring up the pop-up text menu and
>   choose Input Method. Here you can choose other keyboard types,
>   including the default Android Keyboard.
>
> On devices running Android 4.0 and later, whenever the keyboard is on
>   screen you should see a notification in the notification bar that will
>   take you to the input method selection screen when clicked.

Comment: thanks, this doesn't maintain the swiftkey autosuggestions though. I've been digging around in swiftkey-cachefiles, it's not entierly impossible that I could come up with a solution...